# Identity server 4 refresh token to client side

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4, webapi

I am using identityserver api for authentication in my web application.

Whenever token expires I need to forcefully refresh page then it will go to identity and token regenerates and my api gets called in web app.

What should i do if token expires and not refreshed then automatically ot should go and generate new token

Comment: which grant type you use in your project

Comment: if you use grant_type client_credentials and authorization_code then its refresh your token always